# Where to store Images without overriding?

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, storage, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am storing image paths in a database (as suggested by database v filesystem questions)

The images are stored on the filsystem with my website e.g the appdata folder sits beside index file

index.html

/appdata/image1

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to upload my app as a zip folder. I do not want to override the appdata folder as users will be able to upload their own images. Do i need to set up another instance to only hold the appdata ? Are there better services for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS S3 is going to be the best place to store this application data since you are already running on AWS. This would be a very common design pattern - let the code run on your EC2 instance, keep any data that you need off the instance so that you can terminate and restart instances without losing it.